# exclude table with autopostgresqlbackup

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, backup

Is there a way to exclude a table from [autopostgresqlbackup](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/autopostgresqlbackup-backup-your-postgresql-databases-dailyweekly-and-monthly.html) backups ?

I see the `--exclude-table` flag in pg_dump, but is there a clean way to use it in autopostgresqlbackup ?

Comment: What is `autopostgresqlbackup` ?

Comment: well, apparently there really does not seem to exist much doc on it. It's [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/autopostgresqlbackup-backup-your-postgresql-databases-dailyweekly-and-monthly.html). Is there another "standard"' package to handle daily/weekly/monthly backups with rotation ?

Comment: The *more or less* standard way is to create a shellscript that calls pg_dump (and handles the rotation). Called from cron.  I guess `autopostgresqlbackup` does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so apparently, there is no clean way.

You can hack your way to it by editing `/usr/sbin/autopostgresqlbackup` :

```
OPT=""
```

to

```
OPT="--exclude-table=my_table"
```

but that might get overwritten when the package is updated.

Unfortunately, this variable is not exposed in the configuration file (`/etc/default/autopostgresqlbackup`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value (--exclude-table-data=my_table_name) of `OPT` in `/etc/default/autopostgresqlbackup` file.

If not, the default value of OPT ("") in `/etc/default/autopostgresqlbackup` will overwrite the value set in `/usr/sbin/autopostgresqlbackup`.

This file is included in the `/usr/sbin/autopostgresqlbackup` as follows:

```
if [ -f /etc/default/autopostgresqlbackup ]; then
    . /etc/default/autopostgresqlbackup
fi
```